# Mono C# PInvoke - Get CFString from external lib

Tags: c#, c, mono, monomac, cfstring

I have a lib that returns a CFString, and I'm trying to get that string value in C#..
The problem is that I don't know how to do this in C#..

Making the external function return a CFString won't work as it throws an exception "Type MonoMac.CoreFoundation.CFString which is passed to unmanaged code must have a StructLayout attribute."

Then I thought that I could get the string as a byte array and then convert it to a string in C#, but then, I have another problem, I don't know how to convert in C the CFString to a byte array :/

```
C# Dll Import stuff
[DllImport("lib")]
public static extern MonoMac.CoreFoundation.CFString  test();   

[DllImport("lib")]
public static extern byte[] test();     


C Library sample
CFStringRef test()
{
return CFSTR("test string");
}
```

If anyone knows a way to do this please help me out ;)

Thanks

Comment: What is the default calling convention for Mono?  You should declare it both in the C code and the C# and make sure they match.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 [DllImport("lib")]
 public static extern IntPtr test();
```

Then use:

```
 new CFString (test ()).ToString ();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. using UnixMarshal.StringToHeap to convert string to IntPtr.
2. using UnixMarshal.PtrToString to convert IntPtr to string.